# Why do large images stored in database hurt performance

Tags: performance, blob

I have read on the internet that it is better to keep large images on file systems since storing them in the database hurts performance. My question is why do large images hurt db performance?

Comment: The RDBM system would help in addressing such a question as well as what this internet thing argues. With the speed of technology, I'd always consider the date and software versions when discussing performance considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out from a purely theoretical generic RDBMS view with the details posted, however think about what is happening when a RDBMS has to find and sort data.  RDBMS has to track each data page (or lowest amount of data read/written), and it has to track if it's in memory (dirty page), if it's on disk, if it's indexed, if it's sorted physically, if so how, etc.

All of this creates a lot of metadata which maintains pointers/bitmaps and other forms of technology to ensure the proper data is read physically and logically, RDBMS's do this differently based on the technology used but at the end of the day, they have to track each page and what it is associated with.

- Now when you create a large BLOB in a database there is wasted
  overhead that the system needs to manage the locations of.
- BLOBs themselves often require a buffer overflow to point to the
  other data pages that store the same amount of data.  This can lead
  to more fragmentation based on how it's written.
- People often have better disks and storage for databases which are
  often more expensive than just regular old SAS or SATA disks which
  could store images.
- Images don't often require locking/blocking resolution often because
  you don't 'edit' an image in SQL Server.
- Often RDBMS's are RAM driven, so all this data has to go to RAM
  first.  This could change your RAM usage patterns.
- It will make database backups take longer.
- BLOBS are hard to index sometimes based on the type of data.
- Those are just some of the issues you can face.
- Why store the image in the DB when you can just store the pointer and
  have the app open the image?

Comment: Storing the BLOB **in** the database is not necessarily slower: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: +1; however regarding your last point:  guaranteed atomicity of updates.  If the image is updated, the associated metadata in the database is also guaranteed to be updated.  If you store the image outside the database there is no such guarantee.

Comment: Yup there is that.  Filestream might help with that but I didn't want to suggest it to OP since it has a lot of other considerations.  Not sure why I didn't bring it up but very good point.  +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There's more to life than performance, like data integrity. If you only care about performance you should be writing all your code in Assembly.

There is a higher risk of screwing things up by using the file system:

If you keep files in the file system, you now have two things to backup instead of one.

Other stuff: dealing with orphaned files. Dealing with file path security issues (path traversal). Preventing users from accidentally deleting files. You need to replicate your db security to the file system now.

If you're dealing with pictures of cats, go ahead and use the file system. If you're dealing with x-rays, use the database.

If you're so concerned about performance, use the filesystem as a caching layer. Ex: `GET /files/12234` -> if not on disk then fetch from db and put on disk -> read from disk.

Use incremental backup for your database.

Comment: +1, An SQL database is ACID compliant, and you can save the metadata with the related files in a single transaction. Saving them in the filesystem requires a lot of extra thinking and complicated code if you want to do that properly. I am not sure how much they hurt db performance, but you can still cache them on the web server if that would be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can talk only from FILESTREAM perspectives.  But consider storage, memory, and resources.

When an image file is stored in database, it affects the database file size.  What if many images are inserted? If autogrowth is set improperly, the growth can happen so frequently and impact performance.

Also it's effectively encapsulated in another file, and the fact that you'd have to go through the database engine to reassemble the file can be more than nuisance.

Lastly, using the OS file system ensures that the database memory is reserved for query processing.  Pushing large files through the database memory pool can push out the performance benefits stored in cache.

More about FILESTREAM
[FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Actually there are situation where storing the BLOB **in** the database is _faster_ than outside: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: @a_horse Fair enough,  though in this age, below 1MB doesn't seem quite large...maybe for the first generation digital camera? :p

Comment: We experienced something similar here where it was faster to retrieve from the DB (I'm sure cuz of the super awesome DBA right right? jk), but the overhead of doing that was really bad.  It was saved as VARCHAR(MAX) and took down the server once when someone introduced a 2 line bug that changed the row size from 1mb to 500MB